# Getting \today in various languages with polyglossia and tex4ht via alternative4ht

Tags: languages, tex4ht, polyglossia, html

When I use the `\today` macro, I cannot get, in my `.html`, the display in various languages when I compile the following file from 
[michal-h21](http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/fontspec.html#x1-30002) @michal.h21 and [sty file of alternative4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht): **all my dates are in english!**

I compile with  `make4ht -ul filename` . My `pdf` is fine with `lualatex`....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}

\begin{document}
\par\today\par\hrule\par
\begin{czech}
\par\today\par\hrule\par
Praha je hlavní a současně největší město České republiky a 15. největší město Evropské unie. Leží mírně na sever od středu Čech na řece Vltavě, uvnitř Středočeského kraje, jehož je správním centrem, ale jako samostatný kraj není jeho součástí. Je sídlem velké
\end{czech}

\textgreek{
\par\today\par\hrule\par
Πράγα (τσέχικα: Praha), είναι η πρωτεύουσα και μεγαλύτερη πόλη της Τσεχίας. Χτισμένη στον ποταμό Μολδάβα (Vlt}

\begin{russian}
\par\today\par\hrule\par
га (чеш. Praha [ˈpraɦa]) — город и столица Чехии; административный центр Среднечешского края и двух его районов —
\end{russian}

\begin{hindi}
\par\today\par\hrule\par
 प्राग युरोप के चेकोस्लोवाकिया देश की राजधानी है। 
\end{hindi}
\par\today\par\hrule\par





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added basic support for language definition files loading, please update `helpers4ht`. This is the current result:

[image]

Comment: I tried you solution, but if you set `\setmainlanguage{french}`,  I get `(/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf
! LuaTeX error [\directlua]:1: attempt to index global 'polyglossia' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.14   \directlua{polyglossia.load_frpt()}`.I put `enter` to carry and it compiles well with the french date in the `html`. I do not have errors when I set `\setmainlanguage{czech}` or even `\setmainlanguage{german}`....

Comment: On a side note, **for greek, and only for greek,** I get the error, **even before updating the package**, `Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \printlang was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.25 ...· ÏƒÏ„Î¿Î½ Ï€Î¿Ï„Î±Î¼ÏŒ ÎœÎ¿Î»Î´Î¬Î²Î± (Vlt}

?
! Too many }'s.
\textgreek ...guage {greek}\printlang {#1}\egroup

l.25 ...· ÏƒÏ„Î¿Î½ Ï€Î¿Ï„Î±Î¼ÏŒ ÎœÎ¿Î»Î´Î¬Î²Î± (Vlt}` when I compile. DO you know where this comes from ?

Comment: @Koala I've added fixes for French and `\textgreek`. note that while it works to use `\text<lang>` even for texts containing paragraphs, it produces invalid HTML. it is better to use `\begin{lang}` for text with paragraphs.